# Where set java compiler in IntelliJ 2018

Tags: java, intellij-idea

in the intelliJ 2017 I was setting my jdk path in `Setting > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java compiler`.

This setting disappeared in IntelliJ 2018. How may I set the default path of JDK in my IntelliJ 2018?

I know that I may set it in the project structure settings, however, this setting is specific to the actual project opened in IntelliJ. What I'm intending to do is to set it for all projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Default JDK for all the new projects can be configured in `File` | `Other Settings` | **Default Project Structure** dialog.

If you don't have a project open (and no `File` menu), on the **Welcome screen** the same can be achieved via the **Configure** button (with the gear icon) | `Project Defaults` | **Project Structure**.